# Jira CircleCI integration. Please provide a CircleCI API token for this orb to work

Tags: geometry, token, jira, integration, circleci

I'm trying to integrate Jira with circle ci. I've followed the instructions and everything went smoothly. I've 1. installed CircleCI for Jira 2. created token in Jira 3. added that token in Circle CI 4. added orb in config.yml file. When I pushed the changes the build failed and it showed the below message.

> /bin/bash: CIRCLE_TOKEN: Please provide a CircleCI API token for this orb to work!

This is my config.yml file

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
    jira: circleci/jira@1.0.2


workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - build:
          post-steps:
            - jira/notify

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/python:3.6
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          key: deps1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "requirements.txt" }}
      - run:
          command: |
            python3 -m venv venv
            . venv/bin/activate
            pip install --upgrade pip
            pip install -r requirements.txt
      - save_cache:
          key: deps1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "requirements.txt" }}
          paths:
            - "venv"
      - run:
          name: Running tests
          command: |
            . venv/bin/activate
            python3 test_manage.py test
      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-reports/
          destination: python_app
```

[image: Below is the screenshot from my CircleCI configs. which shows that it's connected]

Answer (score 6):

You need to [generate a CircleCI API token](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/managing-api-tokens/) and then [create an environment variable](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/env-vars/#setting-an-environment-variable-in-a-project) on your CircleCI project with the name 'CIRCLE_TOKEN' and the token as its value.

If you want to use a different environment variable name, you can set the [`token_name` parameter](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/circleci/jira#commands-notify) when defining the command in your CircleCI configuration.

Edit:
You [may have issues](https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/jira-connect-orb/issues/56) using a project API token, instead, use a [personal API token](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/managing-api-tokens/#creating-a-personal-api-token).

Comment: I tried personal API and it still fails, then used environment variable pasting the same token value of the personal token.  and now it works